# Cassandra date as column with micro or nano level precision

Tags: datetime, cassandra, precision

I have a column family with datetime value as the column name and the associated value. But since date has a precision at millisecond I am limited to store event recorded at millisecs. How shall I store events recorded at micro or nano level? Also I wish to store them in order and query columns between 2 datetime.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I don't know if nano time fits in 64 bits, but if it does you can use the `BIGINT` data type (in CQL3, `Long` in Thrift). If 64 bits isn't enough use `VARINT` (CQL3, not sure what the equivalent in Thrift is), which supports arbitrarily big numbers. For the rest of the requirements it will work exactly the same as if you were using `TIMESTAMP` or `INT` data type (except that you wouldn't get a `Date` or `integer` back, but a `long` or `BigInteger` -- or the equivalent in the language you're using).